# NSFoundationVersionNumber for ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, ios9

Cani check the version of app for ios 9 like this or is there any other way?

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_0) {
//ios 9 or below?
} else {
//ios 9 above
}
```

Comment: [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the version like that:

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
```

Comment: Yes this will give you the os version, but to check the NSFoundation number is a better way. if you want to now whether you can call a method or class you check whether the calls name is null or the object response tp selector. Check the iOS version is not the correct way.

Comment: It depends on your purpose, you are right. Deniz question is " is there any other way?" so I've just provided one. Cheers